# How to put the footer bar at the very bottom of website?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a live website located here:
[my website](http://goo.gl/flGbfX)

The problem is the footer navigation bar does not position all the way at the bottom of the browser as shown here:
[image]

There is a bit of blue spacing, which is not what I want to achieve.

I'm using twitter bootstrap, if that helps, but the footer bar div object is called "navbar navbar-default"

If I named the footer div like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
```

then, the navbar sticks to the very bottom of the browser window, but it stays fixed, which is not what I want.

Currently, the code is like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Thanks

EDIT: I apologize guys, my website has the footer fixed, but if the code did not have the footer bar fixed, it will have the spacing. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: looks correct in chrome

Comment: I apologize, please look at my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Twitter Bootstrap, but the spacing is most likely caused by padding or margin somewhere between the `body` tag, and/or the `footer` tag and everything inside it. In chrome's code inspector I see calculated margin-bottom of 20px in `<div class="navbar...">`, and also 60px in `<body>`.

A quick test is to modify `<div class="navbar">`:

```
<footer>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin: 0;">
```

See if anything changed. If not:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
```

Tested in Chrome's code inspector and the footer is placed at the bottom without any spacing (and doesn't "stick"), but it's a hack so you should probably find a better way / to follow the bootstrap's logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

You can try this

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```

This an HTML

Below is the basic structure of the HTML code. You'll notice how the footer sits outside of the wrap .

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

You would place your content elements inside the main . For example, if you were using a 2 column floating layout you might have this;

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">

        </div>

        <div id="side">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

A header could be placed inside the wrap but above the main like this;

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way I've been able to get a header/body/footer to work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GHhE8/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="body">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-bottom: -100px;          /* Must be negative height of footer */
}
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```